# Bootstrap nav-bar too long

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my simple navbar.
The problem is I have too much menu items and below a width of ~840px the menu items are misplaced.

The image shows the situation in 3 widths:
[image]
**width: 850px
width: 767px
width: 769px**

Obiouvsly the second one is the problem.

How can I change just the navbar 'breakpoint' and increase the width in which the `button.navbar-toggle` is shown (without destroy the design of the whole site)?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top no-print">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">mysite</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a href="home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="item1">item1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="item2">item2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="item3">item3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="item4">item4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">item5</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="item5.1"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> item5.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="item5.2"><i class="fa fa-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> item5.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned on this website https://coderwall.com/p/wpjw4w/change-the-bootstrap-navbar-breakpoint ( Thank's to the author )
You should change the size of the bootstrap breakpoint , this is an example for bootstrap 3.1 :

```
@media (max-width: 850px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```